# How to check if a specific SKAction with key is running

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skaction

I have an SKAction that is triggered running withKey:"running".
I also have other actions with keys. In my case I would find it handy, if I could check if eg SKAction with the key "running" is currently running or not.

Something like:

```
if (mySpriteNode.runsAction("running")) {
    // do some magic code
}
```

For now I just found that I can look if there are actions in general applied to a node, like

```
mySpriteNode.hasActions
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: When an action is assigned to a node, it is running, there is no way to pause it (though you can pause the node)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You can pause the action which is associated with a key using action(forKey:) method, without pausing the node ( action.speed = 0)...

Comment: Ahh, yes yes, confusing it with playing audio action, good to have a reminder

Answer (score 8):

I found this method. It might be what you need:

```
func action(forKey key: String) -> SKAction?
```

> If an action exists that matches the key, the action object is returned. Otherwise, nil is returned.

You can use it like so:

```
if let _ = mySpriteNode.action(forKey: "someKey") {
    // action is running
} else {
    // action is not running
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if myspritenode.action(forkey: "some key") != nil {
 //runs if action is active
}
```

This solution worked for me.